# Can one caravan touch one oasis at multiple adjacent spaces?

Tags: through-the-desert

In *Through the Desert*:
Is a player's caravan permitted to occupy multiple spaces next to a single oasis, in effect blocking other players from accessing the oasis?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The rules imply that this is permitted.

The section *Linking Oases* in [the rules from FFG](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/00/ad/00ad19ea-6ca7-45e9-9522-4ce5c34b36eb/throughthedesertrules.pdf) (see page 4, left column) includes the clarification

> If a player places another camel of the same caravan adjacent to the same oasis, he does not claim another oasis scoring marker.

Were such a placement not permitted, it would make no sense to specify it doesn't score additional points.

The rules are however clear that in all cases, camel placement must obey the normal rules i.e.

- you must add them adjacent to a camel in the caravan you control; your extra camels will spread around the oasis from where the first camel reached it.
- you can't add a camel that links caravans of the same colour belonging to different players; you must maintain the caravan separation if another player has already reached the oasis with that colour too.